# Converting from URDF to STL

Tags: ros, stl, ros-kinetic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to convert URDF files into STL files?
I know basically we use CAD software to create stl and convert them into urdf to simulate our robots.
But, in my situation, I have only xacro files and I want to 3d print them so I need stl files.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299078/converting-from-urdf-to-stl/) by [koki](https://answers.ros.org/users/36737/koki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

URDF is not directly a 3D model format. Although you can specify boxes and cylinders and so on, these are primitive shapes that are drawn by the tool that uses the URDF. You also do not "convert" a 3D model (in STL format or any other) to URDF; the URDF references the 3D model so that tools reading the URDF know where to look for 3D data to display a link.

I am not aware of a tool that can read in a URDF and automatically use all the referenced models and primitives to create a single CAD model.

If your URDF only uses primitive shapes, then you will need to create those same shapes in a CAD tool (a good simple choice is SketchUp) and create your model that way.

If your URDF references 3D models, then you will need to import those into a CAD tool and place them in the correct positions relative to each other.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0